# Flutter list view builder showing selected name instade of id

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm new to flutter and I want to use list view using flutter list view builder.
I used this data model(user.equipments) to build the list view

[image: userModel]

in here equipmentName comming from equipment model as show following

[image: equipmentModel]

Here is the actual issue, I need to buind the equipment name from equipment model instead of buinding this id "1603739590802". I tried few ways, but those were not woking as expected.

here is the current result

[image: currentResult]

here is my code for list view builder

```
Container(
   width: size.width,
   child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: _user.getSingleUser.equipments.length,                       
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {                      
         return ListTile(
         tileColor: Colors.blue[100],
         onTap: () {
           _addModalBottomSheet(bc,size,_user.getSingleUser.equipments[index].id);
         },
         leading:Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record_rounded),
         trailing: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
               singleUser.equipments.removeAt(index);
               _user.setSingleUser(singleUser);
            },
            icon: Icon(
               Icons.close_outlined,
               color: Colors.red,
            ),
            iconSize: 20,
         ),
         title: Text(
           '${_user.getSingleUser.equipments[index].equipmentName} : 
            ${_user.getSingleUser.equipments[index].yearsOfUsing} years',
         ),
       );
      },
  ),
),
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `equipmentList` is the list of equipments :

```
equipmentList.firstWhere(
  (e) => e.id == _user.getSingleUser.equipments[index].equipmentName).name
```

The name `equipmentName` is misleading, it should be `equipmentId`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer and it works as a magic

Comment: Glad I could help :)